# Sitecore Managed Cloud queries

Tags: sitecore-managed-cloud

I have following queries with respect Sitecore Managed Cloud – DevOps:

1. Can I use Azure DevOps to do application deployment to SMC
   environments
2. Will I have access to Azure portal which contains our
   Project specific Azure resources
3. How the code deployment will
   happen from Azure DevOps (Am I allowed to configure service
   connections and Service principals etc..)
4. When SMC delivers the environment, will they deliver DevOps release pipelines as well? Or
   do I need to configure it from starch
5. Do I have choice of choosing platform (WebApp/Containers) in 10.2 SMC.

Comment: You may want to isolate these into separate questions. If you'd prefer to do more of a discussion, the Community Forums or Slack might be a better option, but for a Q&A site you get best results if you can make the question tie down to one question that can clearly be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, each of these should be their own question, but I feel that these questions do get asked a lot so maybe this is a good place to answer them:

1. Can I use Azure DevOps to do application deployment to SMC
   environments

   *- Yes, you can use any DevOps deployment tool that is able to deploy out to Azure App Services or Containers*
2. Will I have access to Azure portal which contains our Project specific Azure resources

   *- Yes, you will have access to your Azure Tenant via the Portal*
3. How the code deployment will happen from Azure DevOps (Am I allowed to configure service connections and Service principals etc..)

   *- From previous experience, I needed to create the connections and principles myself*
4. When SMC delivers the environment, will they deliver DevOps release pipelines as well? Or do I need to configure it from scratch

   *- Build pipelines are your responsibility*
5. Do I have choice of choosing platform (WebApp/Containers) in 10.2 SMC.

   *- Complicated question ;) this needs to be a conversation with Sitecore*

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project which utilizes Sitecore service for `Managed cloud for containers (MCC)`. Based on my experience I will try to answer your questions. Most of my answers are biased towards MCC and I believe the process will be the similar for `Managed cloud Azure App Services (PaaS)`:

- **Can I use Azure DevOps to do application deployment to SMC environments:** Yes, you can use Azure DevOps (or any other platform like Github, Gitlab, etc) to store the code repository. In fact, every Managed Cloud environment comes with  an Azure DevOps instance to host the following:

  - Git repositories for infrastructure and configuration templates as a code.
  - Git repositories for application code. (you can use this repository to store the code.)
  - Deployment pipelines.
- **Will I have access to the Azure portal which contains our Project-specific Azure resources** Every Managed Cloud environment comes with an Azure subscription that includes:

  - Azure Front Door - scalable and secure entry point for web applications that provides a solution with global traffic routing and WAF capabilities.
  - Azure Kubernetes Services to host:
  - Sitecore roles: CD, CM, Identity, XDB Collection, and so on.
  - Additional applications: Redis Server, monitoring and alerting services Grafana, Prometheus, Alert Manager, Logstash, and nginx ingress controller.
  - Azure SQL Elastic Pools - to host Sitecore databases.
  - Azure KeyVault - for secret storage across the entire environment.
  - Azure Storage - for license storage.
  - Azure Automation - for system monitoring jobs.
- **How the code deployment will happen from Azure DevOps** I believe you are talking about CI (build) pipeline, for which your team will be responsible. Basically, you will need to create a CI pipeline that will handle building the docker images from the code committed in the repository and then push these images to Managed cloud container registry (ACR).

[image]

- **When SMC delivers the environment, will they deliver DevOps release pipelines as well? Or do I need to configure it from starch:** As I mentioned in the first point, Every Managed Cloud environment comes with an Azure DevOps instance that has deployment pipelines. Specifically talking about Managed cloud for containers, the client is provided with the following pipelines to control their solution: `Infrastructure, Application, Pod restart, and Node restart`. Any commits added to the main branch of either repository will automatically trigger the associated pipeline to run.
- **Do I have a choice of choosing a platform (WebApp/Containers) in 10.2 SMC:** I didn't see any documentation for the 10.2 Managed cloud web app (PaaS) (documentation for a Managed cloud web app is till the Sitecore version 10.0), but please confirm with Sitecore team on this.

References:

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/managed-cloud/introduction-to-managed-cloud.html
- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/managed-cloud/managed-cloud.html
- https://www.sitecore.com/products/services-support/managed-cloud